# eval() and parse() returns?

Tags: r

Concatenating a command to generate a list:

```
line <- cat("list(\"iris\" = iris, \"cars\" = mtcars)")

eval(parse(text = line))
```

Seems to return as a ?

Comment: print out `line` before you try parsing

Comment: `cat` prints but does not store its value, as rawr suggested. Fwiw, I think most people avoid eval-parse as much as possible.

Comment: Is there another way? How about for dynamically constructing lists (I have a lot of variables that get piped into a list)

Comment: @Roland are you sure? It's a just a list of variables.

Comment: Possibly you are looking for the `mget` function.

Comment: May I recommend that you ask a new question that more clearly outlines what you're trying to do (it can be hard to pick up from comments - questions offer more space to give relevant detail)? Comments aside, @Roland's answer *is* technically the answer to your question. If the question were re-opened you could post your answer as "here is a piece of R code that achieves the goal I was aiming for".

Comment: If you have an answer you wish to contribute, you are required to post it *as an answer* below. Please do not edit answers into your questions.

Comment: @meagar: OP can't answer because question is currently on hold. Presumably in that case they just have to sit on their hands and hope for re-opening?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes.

Comment: I'll just end this by reposting my solution for the record to benefit anyone else who may have a similar problem. Hopefully it will not get deleted as I cannot post it elsewhere nor am I interested in reposting the question. It is. line <- capture.output(cat("list(\"iris\" = iris, \"cars\" = mtcars)")) eval(parse(text = line))

Comment: @laemto why are you catting, which is sending the output to the screen, and then using capture.output to put it back in a string? Use `paste` and `paste0` if you want to construct strings for evalling, because that will return a string which you can then eval: `eval(parse(text=paste0("list(","x=1",")")))`

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer below, as meagar said; not sure what you mean about "I cannot post it elsewhere". Btw, I think a lot of the confusion is coming from the idea that you need quotes around the left-hand side when writing a list, but you don't. `list(iris = iris, cars = mtcars)` works fine.

Comment: @Spacedman I'm pasting together commands to pipe through (I am greping and rebuilding file names as variables) so the simplest way to show that is by the example I had given. Thanks for the suggestion regarding paste0.

Comment: @Frank OP can't post answer below since the question is currently on hold.

Answer (score 7):

`cat` returns an invisible `NULL`.

`help("parse")` says:

> file
>   a connection, or a character string giving the name of a file or
>   a URL to read the expressions from. If file is "" and text is missing
>   or NULL then input is taken from the console.

Since you didn't pass any parameters to `parse`, R is waiting for input in the console.

However, beyond that I can only say that you should not be using `parse` to construct a list. There is certainly a much better approach, but unfortunately you have not explained sufficiently what your exact input is, what your constraints are, and what the expected result is.